# how can i replace a field of manager in thread

Tags: blackberry

I want to replace a field of verticalFieldManager in thread ,how can i do this

Answer (score 2):

To update the from a separate thread, you need to either be holding the event lock or running on the event thread. The most sure-fire way to do this is the use invokeLater() to put your request in the Event Queue to be processed on the Event Thread.

```
public void run() { //this is your Runnable for your Thread
    //do stuff
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            vfm.replace(oldField, newField);
        }
    });
}
```

vfm will need to be a class variable or declared final to be visible to this.